# Getting a row from a .anno file only when the value of a column is present in a text file

Tags: bash, grep, bioinformatics, cat

I'm really newbie with scripting and also with stack, so I'm sorry if my question is silly or misplaced.

I have to do a task in Bash.

I have a DATA.anno file like this one:

```
ID POP LOCALITY
1  Apu Italy
2  Apu Italy
3  Tir Albania
4  Tir Albania
5  Ber Germany
6  Ber Germany
```

and I have a pop.txt file that contains two of the population names present in the second column of the preceding file:

```
Apu
Ber
```

Now I want to obtain another file containing only the rows of the populations that are present in the pop.txt file. In this case, the output file I want to obtain is as the following:

```
ID POP LOCALITY
1  Apu Italy
2  Apu Italy
4  Ber Germany
5  Ber Germany
```

I've tried with this script but it seems not to work:

```
cat pop.txt | while read line; do grep $line DATA.anno | cut -f 2,3 >> outputfile.txt
```

Comment: This is a very common task: Were it not the header, you could also use grep utility: `grep -f pop.txt DATA.anno`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "ID POP LOCALITY"} FNR==NR{array[$0];next} ($2 in array)'   pop.txt data.anno
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for code.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                        ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  print "ID POP LOCALITY"     ##Printing headers here.
}
FNR==NR{                      ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_fie is being read.
  array[$0]                   ##Creating array with index of current line.
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($2 in array)                 ##Checking condition if current line 2nd field is present in array then print that line.
'   pop.txt data.anno         ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```